# Gravity Forms - Using a Form to Pre-populate A Gravity Form

Tags: functions, hooks, forms, plugin-gravity-forms

I have a custom form (hardcoded, not a GF) on one page I've written myself:

```
<form id="tailor-select" method="POST">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input name="input_9.1" type="checkbox" value="Cover Design" id="choice_2_9_1" tabindex="1">
                    <label for="choice_2_9_1" id="label_2_9_1">Cover Design</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input name="input_9.2" type="checkbox" value="Artwork Creation" id="choice_2_9_2" tabindex="2">
                    <label for="choice_2_9_2" id="label_2_9_2">Artwork Creation/Redrawing/Relabelling <a rel="#artwork" href="javascript:void(0);">read more ></a></label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input name="input_9.3" type="checkbox" value="Map Creation" id="choice_2_9_3" tabindex="3">
                    <label for="choice_2_9_3" id="label_2_9_3">Map Creation</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input name="input_9.4" type="checkbox" value="Indexing" id="choice_2_9_4" tabindex="4">
                    <label for="choice_2_9_4" id="label_2_9_4">Indexing <a rel="#indexing" href="javascript:void(0);">read more ></a></label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input name="input_9.5" type="checkbox" value="Proof Reading" id="choice_2_9_5" tabindex="5">
                    <label for="choice_2_9_5" id="label_2_9_5">Proof Reading <a rel="#proof" href="javascript:void(0);">read more ></a></label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input name="input_9.6" type="checkbox" value="Digital Deliverables" id="choice_2_9_6" tabindex="6">
                    <label for="choice_2_9_6" id="label_2_9_6">Digital Deliverables <a rel="#digital" href="javascript:void(0);">read more ></a></label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input name="input_9.7" type="checkbox" value="Author Liaison" id="choice_2_9_7" tabindex="7">
                    <label for="choice_2_9_7" id="label_2_9_7">Author Liaison <a rel="#author" href="javascript:void(0);">read more ></a></label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Ok! I'm ready to fill out the enquiry form >" class="choose">
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

What I want to do is, if any of these check boxes are 'checked', then that data gets passed to a gravity form (ID = 2) on another page, and the corresponding checkboxes will be check already...

I get that the data needs to be POSTed and that the action on the submit needs to be the url of the page the GF form is on.

I also know that I can use hooks in my functions.php file, but reading the Gravity Forms docs, it says nothing about using a form to fill a form -  well, at least none that I could see/find. Kinda like this:

```
function populate_fields($value, $field, $name) {
    $values = array(
         'field_one'   => 'value one',
         'field_two'   => 'value two',
         'field_three' => 'value three',
    );
    return isset($values[$name]) ? $values[$name] : $value;
}
add_filter('gform_field_value', 'populate_fields', 10, 3);
```

My question is, how do I get the data passed from the custom form to the Gravity Form?

I don't really know where to start I'm afraid

Thanks =/

Comment: Have a read of this -- https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/using-dynamic-population/ -- and then use the `Populate this field dynamically` checkbox on the field's **Advanced** tab.

Comment: Like I said, I've read that, that's where I got the function I posted from. And yeah, that '...Dynamically' field is already ticked

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Check the **Allow field to be populated dynamically** box (done).
2. Enter a parameter name (in this example, I'll call it `my_param`).
3. Add code to `functions.php`:

   ```
   function populate_fields( $value, $field, $name ) {
       // Use the POSTed data if it's there
       return isset( $_POST[ $name ] ) ? $_POST[ $name ] : $value;
   }
   add_filter('gform_field_value_my_param', 'populate_fields', 10, 3);
   ```

Note that the filter is `gform_field_value_{$parameter_name}`, not simply `gform_field_value`.

### Reference

[Using Dynamic Population](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/using-dynamic-population/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. This didn't work. I'm gonna have a play around with and see if I can do it and post my code here...

Comment: I've updated my answer to use the `$_POST` data. Note that this does *no* sanitization or validation.